# Append result by group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function that I'm trying to append the results by group. I've been able to display the result for a single form but unsure where to proceed. Here is the function on Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/XBSVn/

Comment: What do you mean by "groups"?  Do you mean appending more than one element at a time?

Comment: I need the function to be applied to every class individually. Right now its getting the result from the first class of elements and appending the result to each following class. If you take a look at my link you will see what I'm trying to do

Comment: what do you exactly want to do? if you have one star in the text box you want to display only one star corresponding to it?

Comment: I have multiple forms with the same class and I'm trying to display the result in each span based on the value of the input form. If you check my link on jsfiddle you will realize right away what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. note that there is difference between your class names, and your selector only selects first input element:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ratingroups input').each(function(i, v) {
        var star = '&#9733';
        var val = parseInt(this.value, 10)  
        for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
           $(this).parent().siblings('div').append($('<div>').html(star).text())        
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XBSVn/19/)

Comment: Makes it wrong that the `<div class="rstars"></div>` is empty. (sorry for not mentioning in the first comment.)

Comment: So now I have to remove my upvote...and then upvote again?  I thought the first version was more aesthetically pleasing actually :P

Comment: @Lix haha :) I was criticized for having that perspective `:P`

Comment: @RaphaelPerpignand I prefer simplicity :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the typos in the class names selectors(you used .ratinggroups and .ratingroups) and also the textbox selector(you were always getting the first text box to check the value).

Check this updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XBSVn/12/

Change your HTML to:

```
<form class="ratingroups">
    <p><input class="asstars" value="5"/> </p>
    <div class="rstars"></div>
</form>
<form class="ratingroups">
    <p><input class="asstars" value="4"/> </p>
    <div class="rstars"></div>
</form>
<form class="ratingroups">
    <p><input class="asstars" value="3"/> </p>
    <div class="rstars"></div>
</form>
<form class="ratingroups">
    <p><input class="asstars" value="2"/> </p>
    <div class="rstars"></div>
</form>
<form class="ratingroups">
    <p><input class="asstars" value="1"/> </p>
    <div class="rstars"></div>
</form>
```

and your Javascript to:

```
$(function() {
    console.log($('.ratingroups input').length);
    $('.ratingroups input').each(function() {
        var asstars = $(this);
        var stars = asstars.closest('.ratingroups').find('.rstars');
        var display = true;
        if (asstars.val() == '5') {
            stars.append('<span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>');
            display = false;
        }
        else if (asstars.val() == '4') {
            stars.append('<span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>');
            display = false;
        }
        else if (asstars.val() == '3') {
            stars.append('<span>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>');
            display = false;
        }
        else if (asstars.val() == '2') {
            stars.append('<span>&#9733;&#9733;</span>');
            display = false;
        }
        else if (asstars.val() == '1') {
            stars.append('<span>&#9733;</span>');
            display = false;
        }
        if (display) {
            stars.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            stars.css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm new to this. I like to try things on my own first but still a beginner...

Comment: @Lix hahaha :) that's the *"joke of the day"*! +1 I'm just sorry for the Raminson answer not being accepted...